# Multiple polygons with different roll over actions in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to turn several polygons into buttons in d3. I need each polygon to have a different roll over/roll out/click actions.
I draw polygons like this:

```
poly = [coordinates];

poly2 = [coordinates];  

//drawing polygons
chart.selectAll("polygon")
    .data([poly, poly2])
  .enter().append("polygon")     
    .attr(...   //attributes go here
//I add functionality below
    .on("mouseover", function (d) {
        chart.selectAll("polygon")
        .attr("fill","orange");
    })
    .on("mouseout" , function (d) {
        chart.selectAll("polygon")
        .attr("fill","steelblue");
    });
```

This applies all "on mouse..." effects to all polygons. What is the best way to assign different "on mouse..." actions to each polygon? For example, I want `poly` to switch color to `orange` on mouseover, but `poly2` to turn `red` on mouseover.
Here is my [fiddle with the polygon "buttons"](https://jsfiddle.net/arthurtarasov/oosk91h9/), but I was only able to assign the same action to both polygons there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach would be to set the hover color inside the data:

Something like this:

```
poly2 = {
  color: "green",//mouse hover color
  points: [{
    "x": 71,
    "y": 1.5
  }, {
    "x": 75,
    "y": 0
  }, {
    "x": 79,
    "y": 1.5
  }, {
    "x": 75.5,
    "y": 1.1
  }, {
    "x": 75.5,
    "y": 1.7
  }, {
    "x": 74.5,
    "y": 1.7
  }, {
    "x": 74.5,
    "y": 1.1
  }]
};
```

Next on mouse hover instead of selecting all polygons like this:

```
chart.selectAll("polygon")
        .attr("fill","orange");
```

Select the one which triggered it and set the fill color from the data *(check above hover color is passed in the data)*:

```
d3.select(this)
      .attr("fill", d.color);//fill color from the data defining the polygon.
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/w75zq9qb/)

Comment: Thanks, it works great! But what if I want to add `.on("mouseover", loadnewdata)` where `function loadnewdata() { chart.select(".line")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", newdata);}` to load new data onto one of the graphs? Is it possible using the same approach?

Comment: How would I assign a function `loadnewdata` to `poly` properties? I'm trying something like `loadnewdata: "loadnewdata"` after I assign a color, but it doesn't work

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _poly properties_ can you give me a fiddle to explain what you are trying to achieve, and what is breaking.

Comment: I just got it to work. I loaded each polygon separately: `chart3.selectAll("polygon1")...` and `chart3.selectAll("polygon2")...` and then just used `.on("mousedown", loadnewdata1)` for the first one and `.on("mousedown", loadnewdata2)` for the second one.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do something like this would be to assign classes to each polygon based on its index:

```
.attr("class", function(d, i) {return i})
```

The d is the data and the i is the index, so we are returning the index of each polygon as the class. This allows us to do things like this:

```
.attr("fill", function(d, i) { return (i === 0) ? "steelblue" : "red";})
```

So something like this in what you had: https://jsfiddle.net/szjn7u1v/3/.